# How to use PLSQL to change VARCHAR2 to NUMBER data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to move a bunch of data from MS Access to Oracle DB using Toad for Oracle.  I have fields from Access with this kind of data:

ID   TRANS_AMT   AMT

1    ($100.00)  ($20.00)

2    ($30.00)   ($15.00)

3    $45.00     ($10.00)

4    $10.00      $50.00

The source table in Access has the data type set to currency for TRANS_AMT and AMT.  When I created the table for Oracle as the target table I was forced to change the data type to VARCHAR2 due to the parentheses.

What I need is a procedure or function that will remove the parentheses, multiply the resulting value by -1 if the parentheses did exist, and then put that data into a new table based on the ID.

I need this to loop for a LOT of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, TRANS_AMT, AMT ) AS
SELECT 1, '($100.00)', '($20.00)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '($30.00)',  '($15.00)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '$45.00',    '($10.00)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '$10.00',    '$50.00'   FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       TO_NUMBER( TRANSLATE( TRANS_AMT, '($)', '-' ) ) AS trans_amt,
       TO_NUMBER( TRANSLATE( AMT, '($)', '-' ) ) AS amt
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | TRANS_AMT | AMT
> -: | --------: | --:
>  1 |      -100 | -20
>  2 |       -30 | -15
>  3 |        45 | -10
>  4 |        10 |  50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bce53e91c90cfad53b9fd46698022bf4)*

Comment: This was what I needed!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Translate the parentheses to angle brackets and use the "PR" format model of Oracle's `TO_NUMBER()` function.

Example:

```
with test_data ( val ) as
( select '($100.00)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select '($30.00)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
  select '($5,392.00)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
  select '$45.00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
  select '$19.00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  select '$1,837.33' FROM DUAL )
SELECT val, to_number(translate(val,'()','<>'),'FM$999,999.00PR') as_number
FROM   test_data;
```

> ```
> +-------------+-----------+
> |     VAL     | AS_NUMBER |
> +-------------+-----------+
> | ($100.00)   |      -100 |
> | ($30.00)    |       -30 |
> | ($5,392.00) |     -5392 |
> | $45.00      |        45 |
> | $19.00      |        19 |
> | $1,837.33   |   1837.33 |
> +-------------+-----------+
> ```

#### Update re: PL/SQL usage

This works in PL/SQL too.  For example,

```
DECLARE
  l_string_from_access VARCHAR2(30) := '($5,392.00)';
BEGIN
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Number value is: ' || to_number(translate(l_string_from_access,'()','<>'), 'FM$999,999.00PR'));
END;
```

> ```
> Error report -
> ORA-20001: Number value is: -5392
> ORA-06512: at line 4
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  Unfortunately this does not work the way I am trying to use it.  The records I have for VAL and AS_NUMBER are up in the millions.  When I try to use a select statement in lieu of the explicit values I receive the following error:

ORA-01722: invalid number

And the "translate" operator is highlighted within to_number.

Comment: I updated my answer with a PL/SQL example.  If that still does not help you, I think you may want to update your question to clarify _exactly_ what you've got in Oracle (not Access -- the source of the data is irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown you how to `SELECT` the data. To `INSERT` rows into your new table you'd use

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_NEW_TABLE (ID, TRANS_AMT, AMT)
  SELECT o.ID,
         TO_NUMBER(TRANSLATE(o.TRANS_AMT, '($)', '-'), '999,999.00'),
         TO_NUMBER(TRANSLATE(o.AMT, '($)', '-'), '999,999.00')
    FROM OLD_TABLE o
```

No looping required - this'll do it all at one go.

OR - you could just add your numeric fields directly to the existing table

```
ALTER TABLE OLD_TABLE
  ADD (NEW_TRANS_AMT  NUMBER,
       NEW_AMT        NUMBER)
```

and then set the desired values into the new fields with

```
UPDATE OLD_TABLE
  SET NEW_TRANS_AMT = TO_NUMBER(TRANSLATE(TRANS_AMT, '($)', '-'), '999,999.00'),
      NEW_AMT = TO_NUMBER(TRANSLATE(AMT, '($)', '-'), '999,999.00')
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3cc0514f70f9f54b54d6723036a0072)